# Passing file path to php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file

How do I pass a file path from a file input to my php via jquery/ajax? I have an html page with a file input button then ajax passes "form" elements to a php script, but the path is just a filename. As I understand it, it is a security risk, but I can get the path using php...

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

I was using a plain old form and decided to switch to an cooler ajaxy form-like setup.

```
        /* Submit the request. */
        $.ajax
        ({
            type:     "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url:      "ajax/make_preview.php",
            data: 
            {
                filePath:   filePath,
                chartName:  chartName,
                Width:      Width,
                Height:     Height,
                Colors:     Colors,
                flossBrand: flossBrand
            },
            success: function(ResponseData)
...
```

Is there any way to do this without hacking around the security measures? Or do I need to go back to a crappy form to accomplish it? I do not need to see or manipulate the path...just trying to get the file into a gd image object.

Thank you so much,
Todd

EDIT: I should note that I do not want jQuery to do the upload. I am just trying to let php know the correct file to upload.

Comment: Are you sure you will get file info in $_FILES['image'] using ajax?

Comment: Standard ajax doesn't allow file uploads. jquery and similar work around by translating the ajaxified submission into a background normal form submission which DOES allow file uploads.

Comment: @Dipu: no I will not, that is the problem...

Comment: @Marc I am not actually wanting jQuery to do the upload. I am just trying to get the correct file path to the php script so php can do the upload.

Comment: a file input is for sending files from your computer to the server. PHP cannot "reach out" to your local computer and grab a file, even if you pass it the full path. This is NOT possible as it would be a massively HUGE security hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the local file path to the server doesn't help you to upload the file. The file content should be passed via request, the normal ajax cant do that by itself.

You should try file upload plugins like http://www.uploadify.com/ etc.